# Excel Formula to VBA code Conversion

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that allows me to scan columns and rows of data and insert a formula into the blank cells.  I am able to complete this task with the following excel formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(W4),((IFERROR(DATEDIF(MAX($P4,DATE(2016,5,1)),MIN($Q4,DATE(2016,8,1)),"d"),0)/(DATEDIF(P4,Q4,"d")))*$T4),W4)
```

My question is, is there a way I can put this into vba code so that I can run a macro that will automatically apply this formula in a column of my excel sheet across 30 rows? Therefore, the next row would read:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(W5),((IFERROR(DATEDIF(MAX($P5,DATE(2016,5,1)),MIN($Q5,DATE(2016,8,1)),"d"),0)/(DATEDIF(P5,Q5,"d")))*$T5),W5)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: look into `Range.FormulaR1C1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Range("RangeToCopyFormulaTo").Formula = Range("CellToCopyFormulaFrom").Formula
```

Excel will take care of updating the cell references, same as when you copy/paste